# Configure Apache2 to run a cherrypy app with other apps running

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, cherrypy

I have a Cherrypy app that I want to deploy on my Apache2 server. However, the same server serves another app. What are the options to configure Apache to serve both?

Answer (score 0):

That is up to you and your specific requirements. It really doesn't matter for Apache.

Comment: What I wanted to know is: what options do I have? I edited the question